# SFML: dyld: Library not loaded error even though lib paths updated

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, g++, sfml

I am trying to link my program (writing it with vim) with SFML. I have my `src` folder, which contains my code, and the SFML libraries are located at `/opt/local/lib`. This is the command I am using to compile my code:

`g++ src/main.cpp -L/opt/local/lib -lsfml-graphics.2.5 -lsfml-network.2.5 -lsfml-system.2.5 -lsfml-audio.2.5 -lsfml-window.2.5`

The code compiles, however, when running the executable I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/../Frameworks/freetype.framework/Versions/A/freetype
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.2.5.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

This is strange, because `otool -L a.out` tells me that the dylibs are in the correct place:

```
/opt/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.2.5.dylib (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
/opt/local/lib/libsfml-network.2.5.dylib (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
/opt/local/lib/libsfml-system.2.5.dylib (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
/opt/local/lib/libsfml-audio.2.5.dylib (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
/opt/local/lib/libsfml-window.2.5.dylib (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
```

These paths are the correct paths, and `@rpath` is not listed anywhere in these paths, but the error still says that there is a problem with a dylib with `@rpath` in its path, which is very weird. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Turns out that I didn't add the dependencies to /opt/local/lib.